# DMARC record without rua or ruf entry

Tags: reporting, dmarc

I have set up my server with SPF and DKIM and activated DMARC with

> v=DMARC1; pct=100; ruf=mailto:postmaster@example.com; rua=mailto:postmater@example.com; p=reject

So far everything works perfectly, I get reports for ± all emails send via the server (not everyony seems to have implemened `DMARC` reports) and reports for emails failing the `SPF/DKIM` checks.

As far as I understand `DMARC` does many things:

1. Tells servers what do do with emails failing `SPF/DKIM` checks (reject them in my case)
2. Tells servers do send reports for email received (`rua`)
3. Tells servers do send reports for email received which failed `SPF/DKIM` checks (`ruf`)

The documentation on [dmarc.org](https://dmarc.org) seems to imply that I should only activate rejected reports if I'm willing to possibly get spammed.
In my experience the normal reports fir successful mails seem to be a lot more spammy, and less helpfull, and the few

My question is: Do I need the `rua` and `ruf` parts of `DMARC` at all, once I confirmed that all legitimat emails are propperly received, and I don't experience problems with falsly spammed emails?
Is my `DMARC`entry still valid, and will it be propperly applied, if it simply says:

> v=DMARC1; pct=100; p=reject

Comment: Sorry. How can I move it, or anyone other?

Comment: Actually, these are not server settings, but public DNS records containing policy on what is required to consider emails legitimate. These policies apply to ones own servers, but just as much to any SaaS or other software that sends emails on your behalf, marketing tools.. IMHO this question would be suitable for webmasters, information security or serverfault. PS I did read the link for on topic questions and realize the DNS relation, but I consider the question more functional than technical...

Comment: @Rein After further review, I agree and retract my complaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DMARC, [`rua` and `ruf` are optional](https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/how-to-create-a-dmarc-record/). In addition, `pct` defaults to 100.

So your record is valid, but you can further condense it without changing its meaning: `v=DMARC1; p=reject`.

Personally I feel safer collecting the reports somewhere in case there is some weird failure, but that's up to you.